# Find Function locked to the row?

Tags: google-sheets, search, find

Trying to do a find function on a google sheet.

When I search for a specific string it errors out on the wrong cell because its locked heres an example.

```
data on tab 1
(data 1 data 2 data 3 data 4)
(data 5 data 7) 
ETC ETC
```

Data on Tab 2

```
=find(A3, 'data on tab 1'!, 4)
```

when i would run something like this im getting locked to the 3 row on the first tab for pulling the data. Not from the actual spot i need to pull from.
This has been causing an error of

> value# can't find data 3 in data 1 data 2 data 3 data 4.

What am i doing wrong?

https://docs.google.com/spreadsheets/d/1O4u_Cf_6reEiX8kNp8ZD2QKjaUHiNVUKBK831cI_zWg/edit?usp=sharing

Link to a fake sheet im working on that will allow me to see what i need. you all have editor access to this. so if you see where i need it go ahead

Comment: share a copy of your sheet

Answer (score 0):

looks like there is an incomplete reference to a range:

```
'data on tab 1'!
```

should be for example:

```
'data on tab 1'!A:A
```